# Prevent or close Windows pop up after taskkill

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cmd

I use a script.bat in Windows 10 to taskkill Chrome and restart it afterwards. Sometimes I get an error pop up containing the message: 'Application.exe' failed to complete. Error in action 7: Failed to terminate process 'chrome'. Application.exe is running as Administrator. If I press OK everything goes well, but if I don't restarting Chrome will not proceed. Is there a way to use script to close or prevent the error pop up?

I tried the code snippets below:

The first one doesn't prevent the error pop up from happening.

```
taskkill /IM application.exe /T /F 2> nul
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /T /F 2> nul
start "" /wait C:\a\b\c\application.exe
start chrome --incognito --kiosk http://localhost:8000
```

The second one doesn't start Chrome.

```
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /T /F 2> nul
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq application.exe" | findstr /I /C:"application.exe"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1
start chrome --incognito --kiosk http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: I don't know the `Application.exe` however I'd check _ERRORLEVEL_ from `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Application.exe" | findstr /I /C:"Application.exe"`. Then continue  `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` then `Application.exe` has finished and you can restart `chrome.exe` safely. Otherwise, wait e.g. via `timeout 1` and repeat the `findstr` test.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not that skilled.. I tried putting `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Application.exe" | findstr /I /C:"Application.exe"` and `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` between the taskkill and start chrome line, but Chrome isn't starting anymore if I run script.bat. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My crystal ball has gone blind… Please [edit] and update the question: show the last code sticking on the rules of [mcve].

Comment: Sorry Josef, I have edited the original post and also tried to close the application.exe first and restart it aftwards, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following `.bat` script should do the task.

```
@echo OFF
set "_app=application.exe"
:CheckApp
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %_app%" | findstr /I /C:"%_app%" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    REM Application.exe has finished and you can kill chrome.exe safely
    REM without `/F` switch, `taskkill` merely sends termination signal;
    REM `/F` specifies to forcefully terminate specified process(es).
    taskkill /IM chrome.exe /T /F 2> nul
    REM labels are not allowed inside a parenthesized code block;
    REM                                  hence, call a procedure 
    CALL :RestartChrome
) else (
    REM `Application` is running; go back to `:CheckApp` test after some delay
    timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL 2>&1
    GOTO :CheckApp
)
REM script continues here after `chrome` restart
GOTO :eof

:RestartChrome
REM check if `chrome.exe` is still running
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" | findstr /I /C:"chrome.exe" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    REM `chrome.exe` has finished and you can restart it safely
    start "" chrome --incognito --kiosk http://localhost:8000
) else (
    REM `chrome.exe` is running
    REM wait here for some time period to finish `chrome` completely
    timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK >NUL 2>&1
    REM go back to `:RestartChrome` test after (above specified) delay
    GOTO :RestartChrome
)
GOTO :eof
```

The `REM` comments in above code should explain itself sufficiently (considering previous discussions). For more info see **required reading**: [*An `A-Z` Index of the Windows `CMD` command line*](https://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I still get the error pop up: 'Application.exe' failed to complete. Error in action 7: Failed to terminate process 'chrome'.

Comment: Then add `taskkill /IM %_app% /T /F >nul 2>&1` above the `:CheckApp` label. I must say over again that I  don't know the `Application.exe` at all (and possible impact of killing it).

Comment: I have added the line, but I am afraid it still causes the pop up to appear. The bat file  was in the Windows startup folder. I also tried creating a shortcut in the startup folder, run it as admin and put UAC to zero, but with no luck..